# set environment variable with whitespaces in the value using withEnv in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I need to have the effect of `MAVEN_OPTS="-server -Xms4G -Xmx4G" mvn clean verify -f pom.xml` with `Jenkinsfile`.

The below does not work. What is the correct syntax for it?

```groovy
withEnv(['MAVEN_OPTS="-server -Xms4G -Xmx4G"']) {
    sh 'mvn clean verify -f pom.xml'
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove double quotes after the equals sign

```
withEnv(['MAVEN_OPTS=-server -Xms4G -Xmx4G']) {
    sh 'mvn clean verify -f pom.xml'
}
```